# Style file to add border to all buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make a style file that adds borders to all buttons? All buttons already have a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Create your style in file res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="KeyBoardButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>                
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#555</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_border</item>
</style>
```

Define the border that will be used in file res/drawable/button_border.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners
                android:radius="4dp"/>
        <solid
                android:color="#d5cbc6" />    
        <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#dedede" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners
                android:radius="4dp"/>
        <solid
                android:color="#f9f9f9" />    
        <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#dedede" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Now you can use it in your layout files, as follows:

```
            <Button android:id="@+id/my_button"
            style="@style/KeyBoardButton"               
            android:text="1" />
```

Comment: This code is not working when I use background image on button . I want border along with background image